# Reporting Services Report Viewer report not rendering beyond page break

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportviewer, page-break

I have a large report that has summary information that is required on the first page of the report.  To accomplish this I put the summary elements in a rectangle and set a page break after the rectangle was rendered.  This works great when I export the report to a PDF.  However, the report viewer is only displaying the contents on the rectangle.  How can I get the report viewer to display my entire report?

Comment: Did you enable the [ReportViewer toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically the navigation controls? What happens if you click the "next page" button?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your report is not docked in the container and your controls are not visible